# Swift compiler optimisation -O doesn't works after adding Bridging-Header.h

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, compiler-errors, compiler-optimization

For some reasons I'm trying to compare performance of Swift & ObjectiveC. 
For convenience purposes I've made simple Command Line Swift project and added ObjectiveC code there.
Build & Run in debug configuration goes OK.
But Run in Release configuration gives me following compiler error:

**Command /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1**

Sure I can  fix this error by setting *-Onone* in *Optimization level* in build settings.

But as I told above, I need compare code in maximum performance mode.

Thats why *-Onone* is not an option.
You can take a look [on project here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F5zCK0Hs4laFRWOEFqODRxXzA/view?usp=sharing).

Is anyone knows how to get rid of this error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `class Array2D` which is defined inside the extension method
`levenshteinDistanceFromStringSwift`. I don't know if this is a bug or not, but
if you

- move the class to the global level, *or*
- change `class Array2D` to `struct Array2D`

then your project compiles and runs in Release mode as well.

Comment: Is this restriction documented somewhere?

Comment: @Alexey: I don't know :) See updated answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: @Alexey: Btw, your version of Array2D has a memory leak, because the allocated memory is never freed. Also `for i in 0...cols*rows` should be `for i in 0..<cols*rows`, otherwise you write beyond the allocated memory.